# How to sort data in mysql table filed

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have mysql table containing data like this:

```
[{"name":"50_4.jpg","title":"","description":""},   
{"name":"50_5.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_3.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_2.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_1.jpg","title":"","description":""}]
```

how to make it sorted to imagenames be in ascending order like this

```
[{"name":"50_1.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_2.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_3.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_4.jpg","title":"","description":""},
{"name":"50_5.jpg","title":"","description":""}]
```

there is different number of entries in rows and image names are in some strict naming covention

Comment: Your strcutre is unclear, please post your tables definitions. Please also clarify what you mean by "to make it sorted". Data in a table is **stored** with no order by definition. Are you trying to **extract** the data in a sorted order?

Comment: Does a field in your table contains this json ?

Answer (score 0):

use following query to fetch result

select * from tablename order by  name asc;

Comment: Thank you for yours answers, and apologize for being unclear. This is table from Joomla component JEA , I was moving my data to it, and created this strings to be able to show images related to properties.Now joomla component is showing images not ordered by image names, but by order that is in table field, like in my example. Now I need to sort those entries directly in table field to have proper order of images in front end.